# Change Sound of Remote Push Notification locally at iOS level

Tags: ios, audio, apple-push-notifications

I want something like WhatsApp does with notification.

What I observed. 
1. I made a group, and started normal chat. 
2. I closed WiFi (All internet) of Device A, and went to setting and made sound to NONE. See Image Below

[image]
[image]

4. Terminated the app, removed from background. (Yet internet is not connected).
5. Send Message from Device B to Device A, while device A has no internet yet.
6. Switch on the WiFi still the latest sound selected was played on notification. Means No SOUND Played and I selected NONE.

How WhatsApp is handling sound locally.

1. Is it changing payload after coming and before reaching.
2. Is it acknowledging server (how if Application is killed).
3. If it is locally handled, than how.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
import MediaPlayer
```

set the value 1 to maximum and 0 for Min.

```
(MPVolumeView().subviews.filter{NSStringFromClass($0.classForCoder) == "MPVolumeSlider"}.first as? UISlider)?.setValue(1, animated: false)
```

Happy coding

For reference Link [Click](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview)

[Just For Remote Notification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension)

[Follow Video Tutorial for help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yh3lLpV1k_Y)